# check if a key exists with certain "value" exists in an object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object, key, key-value

```
{ foo: [ foo1: true ],
  bar: [ bar1: true, bar2: true ],
  foobar: [ foobar1: true ] }
```

Here is an object with values as `array-like-objects`. I want to find whether a key exist with its value as `[ bar1: true, bar2: true ]`. If a key is associated with the value, then return the key.

I repeat, I am searching the key associated with the value given in an object.

Comment: You cannot have key-value pairs in an array that way, throws sintax error on the `:`. What exactly do you want to use this for?

Comment: thats an invalid array

Comment: that is actually possible. They are termed as "array like objects". For example: "arguments" object for any function. It is neither complete array nor an object

Answer (score 0):

First, that's the right syntax:

```
var map = {
  foo: { foo1: true },
  bar: { bar1: true, bar2: true },
  foobar: { foobar1: true }
};
```

Now to look it up use this function:

```
function findKey(map, term) {
  var found = [];
  for(var property in map) {
    if(map.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      for(var key in map[property]) {
        if(map[property].hasOwnProperty(key) && key === term) {
          found.push(property);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return found;
}
```

For example:

```
var results = findKey(map, 'bar1');
console.log(results); 
// [ 'bar' ]
```

Comment: I am conscious about the syntax. I actually have array-like-objects as values in an object as I mentioned earlier. Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: following your syntax I have tried this
`function findKey(map, term) {
  for(var key in map) {
    if(map[key] == term){
      console.log(key);
    }
  }
}`
I am expecting `foo` when I call `findKey(map, { foo1: true })` but to my surprise it is not logging anything. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert array-like-object to normal array with `Array.prototype.slice.call()`

```
function findKey(obj, key) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        var arrLikeObj = obj[prop];
        var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arrLikeObj);
        if (arr.indexOf(key) != -1) {
            return prop;
        }
    }
}
```